# How to make tkinter text box type out of frame?

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox

I have been trying to make tkinter text box to type out of the visible frame but it always makes words go to the next line with or without `wrap=WORD`. Is there any method to make the lines, not change, when a very long sentence has been typed. Also if a horizontal scrollbar is added there is no use because the words always remain in frame whereas scrollbar is used to see out of the frame things. I want to make the text box like python's IDLE so that unless a line is not manually changed it keeps on writing in the same.
By frame here I mean the visible text box area.
[See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMAn3.png). In the image you can see the text can go out of the frame and you either have to scroll or press R-Arrow key to go to the end but I am unable to make the same in text box.

Please help me with this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, `wrap="none"` turns off wrapping.